# How can i sort results by variables custom value

Tags: php

I have the following if statement. I want to sort by a variable called `$slippercent` variable if  `$slippercent` is between 2.5 and 4 show in top and the rest next.

Let say i have the following records:

```
record A = `$slippercent`=1
record B = `$slippercent`=2.6
record C = `$slippercent`=2.5
record D = `$slippercent`=2.0
record E = `$slippercent`=5
record F = `$slippercent`=4
record G = `$slippercent`=2.8
record H = `$slippercent`=3
```

I want to show as follows

```
record C
record B
record G
record H
record F
```

### the rest orders dont matter

```
 $record = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY (Tread_Design='$rtdesign') DESC, (Manufacturer='$rbrand') DESC,Brand_Name");
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($record)) {
  if (preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($txtbrand)."\b/i", $row['Brand_Name']) && ($row['OD']>=$small && $row['OD']<=$large) && ($txtbrand != "" && $row['OD'] != "" && $row['Brand_Name']!="") ) 

{   
$frontrc= $row['RC'];
$slippercent = round(((($frontrc*$it2t1)/$rearrc)-1)*100,2);
$slippercent2 = round(((($frontrc*$it2t1)/$rearrc)-1)*2000, 2);

echo "<td style='width:60px;  text-align:left; vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['SW'];"</td>"; 
echo "<td style='width:60px; text-align:left;vertical-align: middle;'>";echo $row['OD'];"</td>";
echo "<td id='slippercent' style='width:80px;  text-align:center;'><center>";echo$slippercent;echo'%';"</center></td>";

 }
```

I want to sort or Order if `$slippercent` is between 2.5 and 4 to show on top any order after

Comment: if you store the data into an array then you can use `usort`. But in PHP this is not a feasible way to do that. You need to query like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
ORDER BY slipercent BETWEEN 2.5 AND 4 DESC, slipercent ASC
```

Booleans are treated as `false = 0, true = 1`, and you can use that in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=['recordA' => '1',
               'recordB' => '2.6',
               'recordC' => '2.5',
               'recordD' => '2.0',
               'recordE' => '5',
               'recordF' => '4',
               'recordG' => '2.8',
               'recordH' => '3'];

sort($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $value){
   if ($value >= 2.5 && $value <= 4){
        echo $key . "<br>\n";
   }else{
        $str .= $key . "<br>\n";
   }
}
echo $str;
```

Edited to add you wanted to output the other values outside of 2.5 and 4